# Read Registry Values using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure (CimSession)

Tags: c#, registry, wmi, wmi-query

I am able to query WMI classes and registry values using System.Management and StdRegProv (for registry).

I want to move over to using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure instead of System.Management. So far With help from lot of articles on the net, I can do a CIMSession and get the WMI classes (e.g. Win32_OperatingSystem) etc. with code as below

```
    using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
    ...
    string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
    string OSQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
    CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create("Computer_B");
    IEnumerable<CimInstance> queryInstance = mySession.QueryInstances(Namespace, "WQL", OSQuery);
```

However, reading the registry keys using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure CimSession is eluding me. Could someone pl help guide either with a working example or point me to publicly available resources which can help me accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few months since this post was updated and there is no working code here as well as it's hard to find anything on the web that isn't abstract.  Here is a class I worked on to help you with WSMAN and getting WMI and registry info.

Note: You can stop and start processes/services if you look up the methods for a class, i.e. Win32_Service/Win32_Process.  Use the method `GetParametersForMethod()` in the code below to find out what methods each class has.

To get registry data `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` you'll need to use the `InvokeMethod` method from the `CimSession` class.

To use the class below do the following:

```
string ComputerName = "SomeComputer";
string UserID = "SomeUser";
string Domain = "SomeDomain";
string Passwd = "SomePasswd";

WSManHelper WSMH = new WSManHelper(ComputerName, 
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options.PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos, Domain, UserID, Passwd);
if (WSMH.Connected)
{
     WSMH.GetWMIDataFromSystem();
     WSMH.EnumerateBaseSoftwareKeys();
     // check out the data 
     foreach (string DisplayName in WSMH.RegSoftwareUninstall)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(DisplayName);
     }
}
```

Create new Class with the following:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;
using System.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WSManApp
{
    public class WSManHelper
    {
        private CimCredential Credentials { get; set; }
        public WSManSessionOptions SessionOptions { get; set; }
        public CimSession SystemSession { get; set; }
        public bool Connected { get; private set; }
        public CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem { get; set; } // Only single instance of Win32_OperatingSystem
        public List<CimInstance> Win32_Service { get; set; }
        public List<string> RegSoftwareUninstall { get; set; }
        public string WMINameSpace = @"root\cimv2";
        public string RegistryNameSpace = @"root\default";
        public string RegistryClassName = "StdRegProv";


        public WSManHelper(string ComputerName, PasswordAuthenticationMechanism AuthType, string Domain, string UserName, string Password, uint Port = 5985)
        {
            SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                securepassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            ClassSetup(ComputerName, AuthType, Domain, UserName, securepassword, Port);
        }

        public WSManHelper(string ComputerName, PasswordAuthenticationMechanism AuthType, string Domain, string UserName, SecureString Password, uint Port = 5985)
        {
            ClassSetup(ComputerName, AuthType, Domain, UserName, Password, Port);
        }

        private void ClassSetup(string ComputerName, PasswordAuthenticationMechanism AuthType, string Domain, string UserName, SecureString Password, uint Port)
        {
            if (AuthType == PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default)
            {
                AuthType = PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
            }
            Credentials = new CimCredential(AuthType, Domain, UserName, Password);
            SessionOptions = new WSManSessionOptions() { DestinationPort = Port };
            SessionOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(Credentials);
            SystemSession = CimSession.Create(ComputerName, SessionOptions);
            Connected = SystemSession.TestConnection(out CimInstance TmpInstance, out CimException TmpExeption);
        }

        public void GetWMIDataFromSystem()
        {
            Win32_OperatingSystem = GetOperatingSystemInstance();
            Win32_Service = GetServiceList();
            EnumerateBaseSoftwareKeys();
        }

        public CimInstance GetOperatingSystemInstance()
        {
            return GetClassInstancData(WMINameSpace, "Win32_OperatingSystem");
            // for the Operating system there is only one instance so it can be referenced by setting the index to 0 for the collection.
        }

        public List<CimInstance> GetServiceList()
        {
            // Win32_Service
            return GetClassListData(WMINameSpace, "Win32_Service");
        }

        private CimInstance GetClassInstancData(string NameSpace, string ClassName)
        {
            // default query, i.e. select * from Win32_Service or select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
            return GetClassListData(NameSpace, ClassName)[0];
        }

        private CimInstance GetClassInstancData(string NameSpace, string ClassName, string Query)
        {
            // used for custom query
            return GetClassListData(NameSpace, ClassName, Query)[0];
        }

        private List<CimInstance> GetClassListData(string NameSpace, string ClassName)
        {
            return GetClassListData(NameSpace, ClassName, "SELECT * FROM " + ClassName);
        }

        private List<CimInstance> GetClassListData(string NameSpace, string ClassName, string Query)
        {
            List<CimInstance> cimInstances = new List<CimInstance>();
            try
            {
                cimInstances = SystemSession.QueryInstances(NameSpace, "WQL", Query).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
                // Log error :ex.Message "Error while running method GetClassListData"
            }
            return cimInstances;
        }

        public void EnumerateBaseSoftwareKeys()
        {
            string SubKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            CimMethodResult CimMR = SystemSession.InvokeMethod(new CimInstance(RegistryClassName, RegistryNameSpace), "EnumKey", SetRegParameters(RegHives.LOCAL_MACHINE, RegistryMethods.EnumKey, SubKey));
            string[] RegSubKeyArray = (string[])CimMR.OutParameters["sNames"].Value;
            if (RegSubKeyArray != null)
            {
                CheckForRegSoftware(SubKey, RegSubKeyArray);
            }
        }

        private void CheckForRegSoftware(string SubKey, string[] RegSubKeyArray)
        {
            foreach (var item in RegSubKeyArray)
            {
                string TmpSubKey = SubKey + @"\" + item;
                CimMethodResult SoftwareData = SystemSession.InvokeMethod(new CimInstance(RegistryClassName, RegistryNameSpace), "EnumValues", SetRegParameters(RegHives.LOCAL_MACHINE, RegistryMethods.EnumValues, TmpSubKey));
                string[] SoftWareDataFields = (string[])SoftwareData.OutParameters["sNames"].Value;
                if (SoftWareDataFields != null)
                {
                    string DisplayName = "";
                    string DisplayVersion = "";
                    foreach (var DataField in SoftWareDataFields)
                    {
                        if (DataField == "DisplayName")
                        {
                            CimMethodResult NameResults = SystemSession.InvokeMethod(new CimInstance(RegistryClassName, RegistryNameSpace), "GetStringValue", SetRegParameters(RegHives.LOCAL_MACHINE, RegistryMethods.GetStringValue, TmpSubKey, "DisplayName"));
                            DisplayName = NameResults.OutParameters["sValue"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                        if (DataField == "DisplayVersion")
                        {
                            CimMethodResult VersionResults = SystemSession.InvokeMethod(new CimInstance(RegistryClassName, RegistryNameSpace), "GetStringValue", SetRegParameters(RegHives.LOCAL_MACHINE, RegistryMethods.GetStringValue, TmpSubKey, "DisplayVersion"));
                            DisplayVersion = VersionResults.OutParameters["sValue"].Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private CimMethodParametersCollection SetRegParameters(RegHives RegistryHive, RegistryMethods RegMethod, string SubKeyPath, string AttributeName = "", string Value = "")
        {
            string StrRegMethod = Enum.GetName(typeof(RegistryMethods), RegMethod);
            CimMethodParametersCollection CimParams = GetParametersForMethod(RegistryNameSpace, RegistryClassName, StrRegMethod);
            CimParams["hDefKey"].Value = GetHiveValueFromString(RegistryHive);
            CimParams["sSubKeyName"].Value = SubKeyPath;
            if (StrRegMethod != "CreateKey" && StrRegMethod != "DeletKey" && StrRegMethod != "EnumKey" && StrRegMethod != "EnumValues" && StrRegMethod != "GetSecurityDescriptor")
            {
                if (StrRegMethod != "CheckAccess" && StrRegMethod != "SetSecurityDescriptor")
                {
                    CimParams["sValueName"].Value = AttributeName;
                    if (StrRegMethod == "SetStringValue" || StrRegMethod == "SetMultiStringValue" || StrRegMethod == "SetExpandedStringValue")
                    {
                        CimParams["sValue"].Value = Value;
                    }
                    else if (StrRegMethod == "SetDWORDValue" || StrRegMethod == "SetQWORDValue" || StrRegMethod == "SetBinaryValue")
                    {
                        CimParams["uValue"].Value = Value;
                    }
                }
                else if (StrRegMethod == "CheckAccess")
                {
                    CimParams["uRequired"].Value = Value;
                }
                else if (StrRegMethod == "SetSecurityDescriptor")
                {
                    CimParams["Descriptor"].Value = Value;
                }
            }
            return CimParams;
        }

        public CimMethodParametersCollection GetParametersForMethod(string NameSpace, string ClassName, string MethodName)
        {
            // Returns all In parameters for a given method.  Note: Out parameters are not output as this will result in errors when a query is run.  
            CimMethodParametersCollection CimParams = new CimMethodParametersCollection();
            CimClass cimClass = SystemSession.GetClass(NameSpace, ClassName);
            foreach (CimMethodDeclaration CimMDItem in cimClass.CimClassMethods)
            {
                if (CimMDItem.Name == MethodName)
                {
                    foreach (var ParaItem in CimMDItem.Parameters)
                    {
                        bool isInParam = false;
                        foreach (var Qitem in ParaItem.Qualifiers)
                        {
                            if (Qitem.Name.ToLower() == "in")
                            {
                                isInParam = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isInParam)
                        {
                            CimParams.Add(CimMethodParameter.Create(ParaItem.Name, null, ParaItem.CimType, CimFlags.In));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return CimParams;
        }

        private static UInt32 GetHiveValueFromString(RegHives RegistryHive)
        {
            //HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 2147483648 or 0x80000000
            //HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 2147483649 or 0x80000001
            //HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 2147483650 or 0x80000002
            //HKEY_USERS = 2147483651 or 0x80000003
            //HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = 2147483653 or 0x80000005
            UInt32 TmpRegHive = 0;
            if (RegistryHive == RegHives.CLASSES_ROOT)
            {
                TmpRegHive = 2147483648;
            }
            else if (RegistryHive == RegHives.CURRENT_USER)
            {
                TmpRegHive = 2147483649;
            }
            else if (RegistryHive == RegHives.LOCAL_MACHINE)
            {
                TmpRegHive = 2147483650;
            }
            else if (RegistryHive == RegHives.USERS)
            {
                TmpRegHive = 2147483651;
            }
            else if (RegistryHive == RegHives.CURRENT_CONFIG)
            {
                TmpRegHive = 2147483653;
            }
            return TmpRegHive;
        }

    }

    public enum RegistryMethods
    {
        CreateKey = 0,
        DeletKey = 1,
        EnumKey = 2,
        EnumValues = 3,
        GetStringValue = 4,


    }

    public enum RegHives
    {
           CLASSES_ROOT = 0,
           CURRENT_USER = 1,
           LOCAL_MACHINE = 2, 
           USERS = 3,
           CURRENT_CONFIG = 5
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORMi (https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library instead. It is pretty easy to accomplish what you are trying:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");
var devices = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
```

You can find more information on the repository page. You can return strongly typed objects.

Comment: Thank NicoRiff. I checked it out and it is not useful for me. It is using  System.Management only - which is what precisely I am trying to move away from.